# Infragistics XamDataGrid - cast DataSource back to collection type

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

This is probably a long shot - I'm trying to write a behavior for a control containing a XamDataGrid that includes up and down buttons (to move the grid rows)

I'd like to somehow how access the underlying data source type (which will always be an ObservableCollection of T). Is there any way to pull out the underlying observable collection?

Thanks

Comment: Have you worked with the [DataItems](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~DataItems.html) property?

Comment: my dataitems is always zero for some reason, my objects are in the datasource property

Comment: Also, you cannot guarantee that your underlying grid collection will be `ObservableCollection<T>` unless you are setting that collection type yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull the underlying source from `XamDataGrid.RecordManager.SourceItems` or `XamDataGrid.Records`, this will be the type of the collection you assign to the grid *but* to get to this type you can use the LINQ method `.OfType<T>()`.